# getlastknownlocation always return null after I re-install the apk file via eclipse

Tags: android, gps, location

Recently, I created a simple application to get the GPS location and display it on an Android phone.
In the beginning I was able to get the location after a few tries. But, after I reinstalled the APK file, the `getLastKnownLocation()` always returns a `null` value.

The development environment:

- API 10 Gingerbread 2.3.6
- GPS provider is used

Below is the code I applied to my Android project:

```
public class MyActivity extends MapActivity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myTripMap);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapController.setZoom(14);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    updateMyCurrentLoc(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2, 1, locationListener);
  }

  private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateMyCurrentLoc(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      updateMyCurrentLoc(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras) {
    }
  };

  private void updateMyCurrentLoc(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {

      // other codes to get the address and display
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "provider used : " + provider).show();  //testing purpose
    } else {
      str = "No location found";
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a possible solution to solve the `null` value returned by `getLastKnownLocation()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    Location lastlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

    String CurLat = String.valueOf(lastlocation.getLatitude());
    String Curlongi= String.valueOf(lastlocation.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Does not answer the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is my little improvement for [code by Ravi Tamada](https://web.archive.org/web/20120704044007/http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).

```
    public Location getLocation() {
    int MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10000;
    int MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10000;
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        boolean isPassiveEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled || isPassiveEnabled) {

            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled && location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
            }
            if (isPassiveEnabled && location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

            if (isNetworkEnabled && location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

        }else{
            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add one more line into the code

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                mContext,
                "Location Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if location==null ? How to get exact location

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue after re-install via eclipse.
I solved going to Android settings / Security / app permissions and confirm location permissions to the application.

Comment: That is not the way you need to ask user to grant those permissions in runtime. [for more info check this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)