# getLastKnownLocation() returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-location

I have read a lot of Q&As on this topic here on SO but I have to say that none of them works.

My problem is that, even though I have GPS enabled, I cannot get a location unless I open Google Maps and get my location and then go back to the app, which is definitely not an option for the users.

I have the following function to get the location.

```
public Location getCurrentLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    return myLocation;
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing on how to solve this?
I have also tried this
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#last-known
but still returns null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [getlastknownlocation always return null after I re-install the apk file via eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997079/getlastknownlocation-always-return-null-after-i-re-install-the-apk-file-via-ecli)

Comment: I tried this, didn't work for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there anything I'm missing on how to solve this?

GPS radios are powered down normally, as they are major battery drain. Hence, `getLastKnownLocation()` can frequently return `null` or a stale location, because nothing is checking for location fixes. `getLastKnownLocation()`, therefore, is only useful if you have a casual interest in the location and are happy if there is no location.

If you need to know the location, you will need to use `requestLocationUpdates()` or similar stuff, to cause Android to power on the GPS radio and actively try to find the location.

Comment: Could you point out an example or a link to one?

Comment: @XeniaSis: The documentation has https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html for the fused location provider from Play Services. There is also https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/Periodic and plenty of other examples floating around, findable by a search engine, for using `LocationManager` and its `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: thanks, I'll go through them