# Location with GPS returns null on OREO

Tags: android, gps, android-8.0-oreo

I've tested my App on Android OREO 8.1 (Nexus 5X upgraded), and the location by GPS returns null:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MyApplication.getInstance().
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
     // With GPS
     location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

And *location* object is always null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30665636/115145