# What is the most reliable method to get Location of an android device?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

The method which I am using right now is very unreliable.
In my Android device(not simulator) most of the times the location returned is null .Though sometimes it does work.

```
 public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return location;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know that after the introduction of API 23 there are other permissions I need to take care of.
Is there a reliable way to get location ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997079/getlastknownlocation-always-return-null-after-i-re-install-the-apk-file-via-ecli

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, the most reliable way to get location is relying on 'onLocationChanged' method,  because calling **getLastKnownLocation** method does not mean you get a fresh location or not null result. You can read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) below.

> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this
>   location **could be out-of-date**, for example if the device was turned
>   off and moved to another location.
>
> If the provider is currently disabled, **null is returned**.

And last thing that i want to notice you, calling **requestLocationUpdates** method does not mean it will give you location asap. So this is why i mentioned you 'onLocationChanged' callback method.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the google samples on github related to location:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

How to get last known location, location updates and more