# Getting null point exception on invoking location in Android N.

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to build an app that gets the current location of the device. But it throws nullPointException on:- lat.setText(location.getLatitude()+""); as location object is always null. Please resolve this issue the following code is tested in Android-7.1.1

```
package in.technomenia.user.test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    TextView lat, lng;
    Button getlocation;
    private boolean permission_granted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lati);
        lng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);
        getlocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_latlng);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locations();

    }

    public void locations() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permissions-> "+permission_granted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (permission_granted == false) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 19);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requires GPS Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Locaion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                permission_granted= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "less than android m", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }



        getlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (permission_granted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lat.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
                    lng.setText(location.getLongitude()+"");
                }

            }
        });

    }




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode ==19){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permission_granted = true;
                locations();

            }else{
                permission_granted= false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Hi sir, I have initialized location object in the following line :- location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); but then also it remains null.

Comment: can you add the error code from logcat ?

Answer (score 1):

The `getLastKnownLocation()` method returns the Location value collected after you call the `requestLocationUpdates()` method. If you try to get the last location without request an location update the return will be always `null`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997079/getlastknownlocation-always-return-null-after-i-re-install-the-apk-file-via-ecli) for implementation example
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null) if your location still returns `null` after the location update request

Comment: Thank you sir for your support but it is working fine in lollypop without calling requestLocationUpdates(). Then why is it not working in Android-N

Comment: On the checkSelfPermission() method you verify FINE and COARSE permissions, but on the requestPermissions you only asks for FINE. Try to use: {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);