# Weather is not showing when run on real device

Tags: android

I use **http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather** to show weather it is working in the emulator when I send location in it using location setting but it is not working on a real device.
It does not even show any error message in the log.
Can Any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

I add all permissions in `Androidmanifest.xml` also.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    TextView txtCity, txtLastUpdate, txtDescription, txtHumidity, txtTime, txtCelsius;
    ImageView imageView;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    static double lat, lng;
    OpenWeatherMap openWeatherMap = new OpenWeatherMap();

    int MY_PERMISSION = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Control
        txtCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
        txtLastUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLastUpdate);
        txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        txtHumidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHumidity);
        txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        txtCelsius = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCelsius);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        //Get Coordinates
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location == null)
            Log.e("TAG","No Location");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        new GetWeather().execute(Common.apiRequest(String.valueOf(lat),String.valueOf(lng)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    private class GetWeather extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setTitle("Please wait...");
            pd.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stream = null;
            String urlString = params[0];

            Helper http = new Helper();
            stream = http.getHTTPData(urlString);
            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s.contains("Error: Not found city")){
                pd.dismiss();
                return;
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type mType = new TypeToken<OpenWeatherMap>(){}.getType();
            openWeatherMap = gson.fromJson(s,mType);
            pd.dismiss();

            txtCity.setText(String.format("%s,%s",openWeatherMap.getName(),openWeatherMap.getSys().getCountry()));
            txtLastUpdate.setText(String.format("Last Updated: %s", Common.getDateNow()));
            txtDescription.setText(String.format("%s",openWeatherMap.getWeather().get(0).getDescription()));
            txtHumidity.setText(String.format("%d%%",openWeatherMap.getMain().getHumidity()));
            txtTime.setText(String.format("%s/%s",Common.unixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.getSys().getSunrise()),Common.unixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.getSys().getSunset())));
            txtCelsius.setText(String.format("%.2f °C",openWeatherMap.getMain().getTemp()));
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(Common.getImage(openWeatherMap.getWeather().get(0).getIcon()))
                    .into(imageView);

        }

    }
}
```

**Common.java**

```
public class Common {
public static String API_KEY = "mykey";
public static String API_LINK = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

@NonNull
public static String apiRequest(String lat, String lng){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(API_LINK);
    sb.append(String.format("?lat=%s&lon=%s&APPID=%s&units=metric",lat,lng,API_KEY));
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String unixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setTime((long)unixTimeStamp*1000);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public static String getImage(String icon){
    return String.format("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/%s.png",icon);
}

public static String getDateNow(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

}

Comment: It's because you have not pass your api key to url

Comment: Your url should be like this http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london,uk&apikey=yourapikey

Comment: I am passing it in URL. Please view edit

Comment: Have you tried by hitting url in browser?

Comment: try in postman is your API is working or not.

Comment: yes I do it is showing location.

Comment: In log, it is showing `TAG: No Location`

Comment: Your URL works for me if I put my api key

Comment: If your log shows No Location then error, then problem might be with your lat and lon

Comment: It's working on emulator but not on the real device.

Comment: Can you log constructed URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `getLastKnownLocation` is get the location info when last time, it's may be null.

You can reference other question that keywords: `getLastKnownLocation return null`

These question will help you, may be.

[getlastknownlocation always return null after I re-install the apk file via eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997079/getlastknownlocation-always-return-null-after-i-re-install-the-apk-file-via-ecli)

[getLastKnownLocation returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null)